# How much faster are airmolecules going when the temperature raise from 15 to 25 degrees C?

Tags: climate

As far as I know the temperature of the air depends on how fast the airmolecules are moving. But what is the increase of speed (in km/h) of those are molecules?

Comment: This may be more of a physics question than an earth science one.

Comment: Cross posting on different sites is discouraged. This is really much more suited to physics so it should be deleted here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network and has already been posted there.

Comment: A very dummies calculation.  298 K has 3.47% more heat energy than 288 K.   Because kinetic energy operates on the square of velocity and we assume that mass remains the same, the relative velocity would be the square root of 1.0347 or 1.0172, roughly 1.7% increase in air molecule velocity, however, that doesn't account for changes in air pressure, density, changes in water-vapor, so that number is probably slightly off.  (I suppose this is an answer not a comment, but I'm not 100% sure my calculation is correct)

Answer (score 1):

User LTK 4 is correct. The air molecule is moving 1.7% faster at 25°C.
Marijn can calculate the absolute velocities from the simple equation given in http://www2.ignatius.edu/faculty/decarlo/surfacepower/pages/KineticTheoryOfGases.htm .

And yes, this is more physics than Earth Sciences.